# Inject component on click in a *ngFor

Tags: angular, dynamic

I have followed the tutorial over at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html and it´s working just fine :)

Now I would like to do it a bit more advanced.
http://plnkr.co/edit/D1q7Al60m4UK1weRlcmQ?p=preview

What I want is that clicking on a name should open up the details underneath on a separate row.

eg. clicking on "Luke Skywalker" or "C3PO" should create a row between the first and second row and show the details.

I have tried to dynamically add the "product-host" attribute but not working as the directive expects the attributes to exists.

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons.results" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="33%" person-host>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ViewChildren` to achieve it. There are two possible ways:

1) Just pass index in your `showPerson` function

**template**

```
 <div *ngFor="let person of persons.results; let i = index" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="33%" person-host>
   <md-card (click)="showPerson(person, i)">{{person.name}}</md-card>
 </div>
```

and then use it to determine desired place for info card

**component**

```
activatedViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

@ViewChildren(PersonInjectorDirective) personHosts: QueryList<PersonInjectorDirective>;

loadPerson(person, index) {
  if(this.activatedViewContainerRef) {
    this.activatedViewContainerRef.clear();
  }
  let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PersonComponent);
  this.activatedViewContainerRef = this.personHosts.find((item, i) => i === index).viewContainerRef;

  let componentRef = this.activatedViewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  (<PersonComponent>componentRef.instance).person = person;
}

showPerson(person, index: number) {
  this.loadPerson(person, index % 2 ? index : index + 1);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.activatedViewContainerRef) {
    this.activatedViewContainerRef.clear();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nQL90njDo9GEvstNaWh?p=preview)**

2) You can also build it without `PersonInjectorDirective`. In this case you need to declare template variable (`#refs`):

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons.results; let i = index" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="33%" #refs>
  <md-card (click)="showPerson(person, i)">{{person.name}}</md-card>
</div>
```

and change `ViewChildren` expression as follows:

```
@ViewChildren('refs', { read: ViewContainerRef}) personHosts: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EShhUp9wnjKvTk3iDKQs?p=preview)**

Comment: Thx a bunch! Really nicely explained!.. is there any pros/cons with PersonInjectorDirective or not?

Comment: I think if you use it often then it is reasonable. Especially if you use such types like `PersonInjectorDirective` for relation between some architectural parts of application. Many teams adhere this approach https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/portal/portal-directives.ts#L28